# PostgreSQL - Create Role - Permission Matrix

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables, Roles, Permissions, and Role_ Permissions

```
Table Roles has the following: id, role_name
Data:   id, role_name
         1, Accounting
         2, Order_Entry
         3, Shipping

Table Permission has: id, permission _name
Data:   id, permission _name
         1, Admin
         2, Super_User
         3, Read_Write
         4, Read_Only

Table Role_ Permissions has: 
     role_id (FK from Roles), 
     permission_id (FK from Permissions)
```

I need to create a matrix that looks like this:

```
Heading:       Roles        Admin Super_User Read_Write Read_Only
Columns/Rows:  Accounting     X        X
               Order_Entry    X                  X          
               Shipping       X                             X
```

The 'X' represent that there is a permission for that role. Blanks, of course, mean there is no permission for that role
Can this be done in SQL

Comment: [crosstabs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html)?

Comment: [ACLs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html)?